# Sonar-runner Exception with .NET Project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, sonarqube

I am trying to use Sonar with my .NET project (I have installed the [c# plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin)), but When I launch sonar-runner with this .properties file :

```
# identifiants du projet
sonar.projectKey=key.myproject
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# fichier .sln
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file="d:\dossier-source\myproject.sln"

# répertoires de sources
sources="d:\dossier-source"

# Tests
tests="d:\dossier-source\myproject.Tests"

# langage
sonar.language=cs
```

I have this exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.
>   picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method
>   'public fin al void
>   org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.start()', instance
>   'org.son ar.plugins.csharp.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder@11ecab56,
>   java.lang.RuntimeExc eption: wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You should put this properties file in the same folder as your SLN file ("d:\dossier-source"), and with the following properties only:

```
sonar.projectKey=key.myproject
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sources=.
sonar.language=cs
```

And then run "sonar-runner" from "d:\dossier-source".

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, I have always an exception caused by Gallio. I have to install Gallio ?

In final, I would run Sonar with TFS.

Comment: Yes, you have to install Gallio, all this is explained on the documentation page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/1.+Install#id-1Install-Installtherequiredtools

Comment: I have an exception "Gallio execution failed" Caused by: org.sonar.dotnet.tools.gallio.GallioException: No test assembly was f
ound. Please check your project's Gallio plugin configuration. I have added tests=myproject.Tests but nothing

Comment: The property "tests=" is useless: the C# plugins look into your SLN file to find out which projects are test projects, based on the "sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern" property which defauls to "*.Tests".

Comment: Thanks for your response, my test project name is myproject.Tests :-/ but doesn't work

Comment: So I think you'd better send a mail on the Sonar user mailing list, it will be easier to help you (see http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/) and you'll be able to send excerpts from your configurations files (SLN & co).